# Unable to get data in asp.net 5 web api - environment.cs not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've been having a hard time creating a webapi using Visual Studio 2015 (.NET framework).

I've followed a number of tutorials creating some that return hard coded values, and some that have created a new database/tables.  What I need to do is get/post values to/from an existing database.  I created the code, but when I run it with fiddler, I just get a 500 error and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Breakpoints get me as far as my controller, to the return _clinicalSiteRepo.GetSites(); line.

If I step in with F11 I get an error telling me environment.cs is not found.. if i step over with F10, i get Future.cs  not found.

Code is as below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ClinSiteController : Controller
{
    public IClinSiteRepo _clinicalSiteRepo { get; set; }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<ClinSite> GetSites()
    {
        return _clinicalSiteRepo.GetSites();
    }
```

I'm a bit at a loss as this is really my first attempt at getting live data - I can post the other code on request.

Please edit or let me know if I'm missing something critical in posting, this is my first post to stackoverflow.

Comment: You have an exception being thrown by this call: `_clinicalSiteRepo.GetSites()`. You must find out what this exception is to proceed. You need to add exception handling and logging to see what the exception is. Google "try catch c#" for exception handling information, and "log4net" for a good logging library.

Comment: Alternatively, since you are already in the debugger, Visual Studio should be presenting you with a dialog that includes the magic phrase "Copy exception details to clipboard". Click that link, then paste into Notepad, and you should have your actual exception

Comment: Oh - in addition to my 2nd comment, you may need to enable breaking on unhandled exceptions. You will need to break on "managed" exceptions.

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed by the lack of try/catch, but anyway - it gives:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm wondering if it is having a hard time getting to the database, but the connection string is good.. and not sure how to check if connected with EntityFramework